# Nextjs Bug after downgrading node and then reinstalling back to the original version of node

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js, choco

I had to remove the current version of the node and downgrade to a later version to finish up with another project. Afterwards I reinstalled back to version 20 of node, but my nextjs project hasn;t been working ever since!!!

```
PS C:\Github\portfolio.2.0> npm start

> portfolio.2.0@0.1.0 start
> next start

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.1
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Github\portfolio.2.0\.next\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Github\\portfolio.2.0\\.next\\BUILD_ID'
}
```

any one know how to fix this?

I should have been able to run the application. Now its says the buildid file is missing?

Comment: run `npm dev` to run in development mode, or rebuild your project with `npm build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no build folder. Run 'npm run build' script to build your project and then run 'npm run start'.